# Can someone explain parallelism in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I've heard that python can't do real parallelism, but does support concurrency. This statement means that it's possible to write programs that perform threading but don't actually use multiple cores due to the GIL.

I thought "that can't possibly be true", and so I wrote a little test program to double all values in a list and time the operation. My results indicate that python3 actually uses multiple cores.

```
import threading
import time

def doublearr(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] *= 2


n = 100000000
l = [1 for x in range(n)]
nthreads = 1
block = int(n / nthreads)
threads = [threading.Thread(target=doublearr, args=(l[(x * block):((x + 1) + block)],)) for x in range(nthreads)]

start = time.perf_counter()

[t.start() for t in threads]
[t.join() for t in threads]

end = time.perf_counter()

print(f'Operation took {end - start}')
```

If I run this program with 1 thread it takes about 7 seconds. With 4 threads it takes about 1.7 seconds; nearly a quarter of the time. This time is consistent with what I would expect from a program actually using multiple cores.

So what's going on here?

Comment: What's going on is a typo.  Check your arguments.  You have a `+` instead of a `*` in the second parameter of the list slice and are only running against a fraction of the list.  Add a `print(len(l))` in `doublearr` to see the problem.
Once you fix it you'll get the same approximate time for 1 thread and 4 threads.  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Dang it, you're right. It makes me sad that's how that actually works. I can see why the GIL is so controversial because this behavior makes python worthless for even trivial parallel computation.

Comment: BTW that's an answer, Mark

Comment: It's a typo and there is a specific close reason for it.  It's not likely to help future users.  FYI, use `multiprocessing` instead of `threading` for true parallelism, but there are process startup and interprocess communication overheads.